# Extract the content of the script with PHP Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I want to extract the content of the script on [this page](https://www.technolife.ir/product-3291/%DA%AF%D9%88%D8%B4%DB%8C-%D9%85%D9%88%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%8A%D9%84-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%88%D9%86%DA%AF-%D9%85%D8%AF%D9%84-galaxy-a12-nacho-%D8%B8%D8%B1%D9%81%DB%8C%D8%AA-128-%DA%AF%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA---%D8%B1%D9%85-4-%DA%AF%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA), which has the ID `__NEXT_DATA__` using `PHP Simple HTML DOM`, the code I wrote is this:

```
foreach($html_base->getElementsByTagName('script') as $element) {
                if (isset($element->id)){
                    $id = $element->id;
                    if ($id == "__NEXT_DATA__"){
                        $f = $element->nodeValue;
                        echo $f;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            
            }
```

but unfortunately it gives me the following error:

`Undefined property: DOMElement::$id`

Comment: There are other scripts that don't have an ID. You should test whether the element has an ID before assigning it to a variable.

Comment: You won't find the element, because it is rendered later by the browser. **DO NOT STEAL OTHER WEBPAGES DATA**. Ask for an API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple html dom [documentation](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/manual/finding-html-elements/) but here's my suggestion:

```
$html = file_get_html("url");
$script = $html->find("script[id=__NEXT_DATA__]", 0)->innertext;
```

the second parameter which is 0, is the index of the searched results and because it's only one script with this id, you can take the first result.

Comment: it gives me the following error: `Call to undefined method DOMDocument::find()`

Comment: Are you using sourcefourge simple html dom?

Comment: If not then use it. It's much easier